# AngularJS using Webservice

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

How do I create an example of angularjs using webservice in asp.net?
How do I create a webservice in angularjs?

I have created a simple example of angularjs but how do I create a angularjs Webservice?

Comment: What is this code for?

Comment: Can you use Web.Api?

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a WCF Service and consume it in your AngularJS Application.

1. Create a WCF Service that returns JSON Data.
2. Host it on IIS.
3. Create an AngularJS Application.
4. Consume the WCF Service in AngularJS Application.

[This](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1051) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/crud-operation-in-mvc4-using-angularjs-and-wcf-rest-services/) links are simple examples of what you want to do.